# How do I use AES_Decrypt

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I know this question has been asked a billion times as I've spent the last 2 weeks looking at all the previously asked questions and answers
but none of them actually have an understandable answer. So my question is this, I have a form that I'm passing the data input by users into a mysql
database and a portion of that data is encrypted with AES_Encrypt. When I check the database I can see the data has been encrypted so I'm good on the encryption part.
My issue lies in the decryption part. I've tried multiple variations from previous questions asked with no success, This is what I have so far,

```
//ENCRYPTING DATA
require 'path to key.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO applications "(fname, lname, dob, ssn) VALUES  ('$fname', '$lname', '$dob', AES_ENCRYPT('$ssn', '".$aeskey."')";
```

The code above works fine to encrypt the string.

This is where I'm confused, I'm wanting to select all the data associated with the ID for a record and decrypt the encrypted data for that record as well,
for example I have a search form that pulls up all the records in the database, you can then select to view a record and the results display in a form similar to the form used
to input the information.

So in my form to view records I have the following code.

```
//DECRYPT DATA

require 'path to key.php';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  


$data = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where ID = $id";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $data);

$data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

<input type = "text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $data2['fname']?>"/>
<input type = "text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $data2['lname']?>"/>
<input type = "text" name="dob"   value="<?php echo $data2['dob']?>"/>
<input type = "text" name="ssn"   value="<?php echo $data2['ssn']?>"/><-----This will display the encrypted data in the encrypted form
```

So do I need to decrypt the encrypted data from the input box like

```
 <input type = "text" name="ssn" value=<?php echo [AES_DECRYPT('ssn', '$aeskey')]?>"/> <---Doesn't work
```

or do I need to do something like this:

```
$sql SELECT * FROM $tbl_name (AES_DECRYPT('ssn', '$aeskey')) WHERE ID=$id;
```

Or am I totally wrong in how I think AES_DECRYPT should be used?

Comment: You have incredibly many PHP syntax errors. It has something to do with your quotes. You should see that the syntax highlighting is very off.

Comment: You should never build the SQL queries yourself. You really need to use prepared statements. Otherwise, your site will be vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Artjom B. The question has nothing to do with PHP syntax errors or SQL injection this is an example not the actual code so your answers are off topic

Comment: Actually there is a threat of cleartext in the sql logs too.

Comment: @Rich Those are comments that I posted on your question so that you can improve your question and not make your site trivially breakable. Comments are not only for you, but also for future readers to alert them of the (security) issue of this question. There are far too many people that are blindly copying code from the internet. It's best to give them a chance to determine if they really want to copy bad/broken code.

Comment: @Artjom B This is EXACTLY why I have refrained from asking any questions on this site for a very long time. Too many people want to go off topic with sql injection or syntax errors instead of just answering the OP's question. It's almost as if this site is full of trolls that do nothing but comment on how an OP has sql injection vulnerabilities. And if they do have them so what, they're not here asking about that, they'll figure it out soon enough and fix the problem.  But I can gurantee I will NEVER ask another question on this site EVER again!

Comment: If you're asking a question and are not prepared to receive some constructive criticism, then perhaps this is indeed the wrong site for you. Remember, that this criticism is not only for you but for future readers. Do you think we volunteer our valuable time just to answer questions for individual people? No, most do this to help future readers by helping you in the short term. So, we have an obligation to point out mistakes and insecure code. At the moment you post something on this site it is not really yours anymore and it is subject to moderation in various forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `INSERT` you use [AES_ENCRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) (of MySQL); then you have in your `SELECT` apply `AES_DECRYPT`; ejem:

```
SELECT fname, lname, dob, AES_DECRYPT(ssn, yourAESKey) as ssn
FROM applications [wHERE ... and other more that you require]
```

See that `AES_DECRYPT` have alias to return of result.

## EDITED

Only change in `$data` the string with the SQL:

```
$data= "SELECT fname, lname, dob, AES_DECRYPT(ssn, yourAESKey) as ssn
        FROM applications [WHERE ... and other more that you require]"
```

You line: `<input type = "text" name="ssn"   value="<?php echo $data2['ssn']?>"/><-----This will display the encrypted data in the encrypted form` not change; unless instead of **ssn** (all in lowercase) in the alias you change some letter or all the letters to capital letters, you assign another alias name to the decrypted text; In order not to be **ssn** (in lower case).

Comment: @ Roberto Leon Oramas I've tried the method you suggest in other stackoverflow answers with no success. I need a solution that, 1.) Actually decrypts the encrypted data and 2.) works with  SELECT * FROM applications WHERE ID = $id.   I have over 100 variables and need to select ALL of them from the database to display in the form when it's pulled up as well as decrypt the SSN.  Do I need to run 2 queries? 1 calling for all the data in the table and the 2nd to decrypt the SSN?

Comment: If I implement this line of code from the command line of MySQL  SELECT aes_decrypt(ssn, '123456789abcdefghijklmnop') FROM applications WHERE ID = '52'   It will display the decrypted SSN so I know I'm close I just need to know how to make it work in my php form. How do I get the decrypted SSN to display in the input box for SSN?

Comment: @ Roberto Leon Oramas, Thanks for your help I've figured it out, I ran a second query with just SELECT AES_DECRYPT(ssn, '$aeskey') ssn FROM $tbl_name WHERE ID = '$id'  and left my input value as ['ssn'] and now it displays the decrypted value. I guess the simple things are easy to miss as I forget the ssn before FROM $tbl_name.